# How do i correct the syntax?

Tags: verilog

This is the code written for Page rank algorithm in verilog:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps


module PR1();

wire [7:0] links[3:0][3:0];
wire [7:0] links_t[3:0][3:0];
wire [7:0] out_links[3:0];
wire [7:0] p[3:0];
genvar loop,k,i,j;
real d = 0.85; //damping factor
wire [7:0] p_new[3:0];

// hard coded assignment of links
assign links[0][0]=0;
assign links[0][1]=1; // 1 -> 2
assign links[0][2]=0;
assign links[0][3]=0;
assign links[0][4]=1; // 1 -> 5

assign links[1][0]=0;
assign links[1][1]=0;
assign links[1][2]=1; // 2 -> 3
assign links[1][3]=0;
assign links[1][4]=0;

assign links[2][0]=0;
assign links[2][1]=0;
assign links[2][2]=0;
assign links[2][3]=0;
assign links[2][4]=1; // 3 -> 5

assign links[3][0]=0;
assign links[3][1]=0;
assign links[3][2]=0;
assign links[3][3]=0;
assign links[3][4]=1; // 4 -> 5

assign links[4][0]=0;
assign links[4][1]=0;
assign links[4][2]=0;
assign links[4][3]=1; // 5 -> 4
assign links[4][4]=0;

// initialise the vectors p
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1)begin
assign p[i] = 1/5;
end

generate
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1) begin
for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j=j+1) begin
if(links[i][j] != 0) begin  `//line 72`
assign out_links[i] = out_links[i] + 1;
end
end
end
endgenerate

// make the matrix stochastic
generate
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1) begin
if (out_links[i] == 0) begin `//line 82`
for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j=j+1) begin
assign links[i][j] = 1/5;
end
end
else begin
for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j=j+1) begin
if (links[i][j] != 0) begin `//line 89`
assign links[i][j] = links[i][j] / out_links[i];
end
end
end
end
endgenerate

// transpose the matrix
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1) begin
for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j=j+1) begin
assign links_t[i][j] = links[j][i];
end
end

// page rank loop
for (loop = 0 ; loop < 10 ; k = k + 1) begin
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1) begin
//assign p_new = 0;
end

for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1) begin
for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j=j+1) begin
assign p_new[i] = p_new[i] + (links_t[i][j] * p[j]);
end
end

for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1) begin
assign p_new[i] = d * p_new[i] + (1.0 - d) / 5;
end

end
for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i=i+1) begin
initial 
$display("PR of i is %f",p_new[i]);
end
endmodule
```

Which gives the error messages

```
 ERROR: [VRFC 10-60] links is not a constant [C:/Users//CP/CP.srcs/sources_1/new/PR1.v:72]
 ERROR: [VRFC 10-60] out_links is not a constant [C:/Users//CP/CP.srcs/sources_1/new/PR1.v:82]
 ERROR: [VRFC 10-60] links is not a constant [C:/Users//CP/CP.srcs/sources_1/new/PR1.v:89]
 ERROR: [VRFC 10-1040] module PR1 ignored due to previous errors [C:/Users//CP/CP.srcs/sources_1/new/PR1.v:23]
```

I am not able to use the conditional statements that has indexing properly.
Please help me to resolve the errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `generate` block, values used as conditionals (e.g. in `if` or `for` statements) must be constants. The reason is simple - `generate` loops are unravelled by the synthesis tools into selecting what hardware should appear in the final design. If the value could change, then it would infer hardware that exists one minute, and then vanishes the next.

Constants here must be in the form of a `parameter`, a `localparam`, a numeric constant (`2'd3`), or a `genver`.

However you have three places where you try to use a `wire`, e.g.:

```
if (out_links[i] == 0)
```

This is not valid, because the `wire` is not considered a constant here, even though it is driven by one (you could in a simulator for example force the wire to a different value, so it cannot be considered a constant).